# "Form" - If-else Statements

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to realize a simple form:

there's a globalname and globalpass, and the User is asked to type in his name and pass.

```
If name == globalname and pass = globalpass -> "Hello name"
If name == blank or pass == blank -> "O NOEZ, you fergit sumpn!"
If name != globalname or pass != globalpass -> "WHUT? Who be you, intruder?"
```

So far I only manage to get the first if-working...

```
<% 
  String name = request.getParameter("name");
  String pass= request.getParameter("pass");
  String globalname = "webeng";
  String globalpass = "2009";
  if (name !=null && pass!=null && name.equals(globalname) && pass.equals(globalpass))
   {
%>
    <jsp:include page="formular-modul1.jsp" />
<% } else
   {
%>
<% }
%>

<%
 else if (name =="b" && pass =="c" && name.equals("b") && pass.equals("c"))
  {
%>
    <jsp:include page="formular-modul2.jsp" />
<%} else
    {
%>
<%
}%>
```

The name=="b" && pass =="c" was just for test purposes, which failed! Can somebody help me out, please?

Comment: The OP continued in another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738294/convert-typed-in-text-to-lowercase

Answer (score 2):

Strings are **objects**, not **primitives**. When using `==` to compare objects, it would only return true if both points to the same *reference*. It doesn't test the object's value. There you already have `Object#equals()` for.

Apart from this problem, using those old fashioned scriptlets in a JSP file is a sign of a bad practice. In this specific case you'd better use a Servlet class for this. Good luck.

Comment: I'm just starting with JSP. I will use Servlets, when I come to it. Right now I have to use Scriptlets.

Even with if (name.equals("b") && pass.equals("c")) it aint working!

Comment: It's hard to spot the error when you're using ugly scriptlets and you don't elaborate about the actual problem. "it aint working" gives us basically nothing to work with. I recommend to create a Java class which does the task and test it using main(). Or you can put a bit more effort in elaborating the problem and tell what actually is happening at code level (including exceptions/errors).

Comment: Oh, don't forget to read the appserver logs. As you're using scriptlets, you won't see any exceptions with helpful debugging information at the page but just a blank nothing-saying page in case of failure. My cents on a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now.

```
<% 
  String name = request.getParameter("name");
  String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
  String globalname = "webeng";
  String globalpass = "2009";
  if (name !=null && pass!=null && name.equals(globalname) && pass.equals(globalpass))
   {
   %>
    <hr />
    <p><b>Howdy, <%= request.getParameter("name") %></b></p>
    <hr />
<% }
  else if (name !=null | pass!=null && name.equals("") | pass.equals(""))
  {
  %>
    <hr />
    <p><b>Ooops, one or more fields are empty. Please fill everything out!!</b></p>
    <hr />
<% }
  else if (name !=null | pass!=null && !name.equals(globalname) | !pass.equals(globalpass))
  {
  %>
    <hr />
    <p><b>Incorrect Userdata!</b></p>
    <hr />
<% }
  else{
  }
%>
```

Now I need to use .toLowercase.

Means name and pass have to be converted into .toLowercases THEN used. Anyone got any idea? Simply using newname = name.toLowercase(); or newpass = pass.toLowercase(); doesn't work!

Comment: The `String` class has a `equalsIgnoreCase()` method. Guess what it does :)

Comment: By the way, I really won't consider "PaSsWoRd" and "password" as equal.

Comment: Neither would I. this .jsp doesn't consider "password" and "PaSsWoRd" equal. If globalpassword is password, then PaSsWoRd returns "Incorrect Userdata!"

Comment: `String#toLowercase()` yields a new string. Because Strings are immutable. It should work ok if you assgn the `.toLowercase()` to a new variable.
In your code above, you use `|` operators which are bitwise OR and do NOT shortcut the conditional evaluation. What you are looking for is the `||` logical OR operator.

Comment: Then what's the point of doing `pass.toLowercase()` ? Just don't do that. By the way, if you still have problems, you really, really need to elaborate "doesn't work!" in *more* detail.

Comment: Because I want and need to. BalusC

Comment: The point I want to use .toLowerCase is because folks my type in WebEng, but the globalname is webeng. So I need the typed in "WebEng" transformed into "webeng" in order for it to be correct. The point WHY HOW doesn't matter. I just want and need it to.