# Creating Notepad in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a notepad application in Java.I have created the text area also the menus .I have a menu called "EDIT" and under that I have "UPPERCASE"..If i select a particular text and click on "UPPERCASE" ,I want the string to be converted into uppercase.
  Can anyone tell me how to implement this in Java.

Comment: Java's string class has a toUpperCase() method... Or are you asking about how to you find the selected text? It's likely a propery of your control...

Comment: If you use awt, change it to swing!

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by using the following methods:

- `JTextArea.getSelectionStart()`
- `JTextArea.getSelectionEnd()`
- `JTextArea.getText()`
- `String.toUpperCase()`
- `JTextArea.replaceRange()`

Comment: Its not working.My uppercase menu is enabled.And I have 

else if(e.getsource()==this.upper)
{
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("some text");
int start = textArea.getSelectionStart();
int end = textArea.getSelectionEnd();
String replace = textArea.getSelectedText().toUpperCase();
textArea.replaceRange(replace, start, end); 
}
But still its not working..CAn you tel me wat to do?

Comment: @Saranya.R: of course you have to use the JTextArea you are displaying to the user, not one you create locally.

Answer (score 6):

[String.toUpperCase()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())

Answer (score 4):

The `String` class has [`toUpperCase()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) and [`toLowerCase()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) methods that you can use. Here's an example:

```
    System.out.println("Hello World!".toUpperCase());
    // prints "HELLO WORLD!"

    System.out.println("FOO $@&# BAR".toLowerCase());
    // prints "foo $@&# bar"
```

They also have overloads that takes a [`java.util.Locale`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) if you need to do locale-specific transformation.

#### Related questions

- [How do I convert strings between uppercase and lowercase in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951856/how-do-i-convert-strings-between-uppercase-and-lowercase-in-java)
- [Convert typed-in Text to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738294/convert-typed-in-text-to-lowercase)

---

#### Reminder: `String` is immutable

`String` is immutable: you can't invoke a method that will mutate the string instance it's invoked upon. The following is a common beginner's mistake:

```
    String text = "  blah blah bloop  ";
    text.toUpperCase();
    text.trim();
    System.out.println(text);
    // prints "  blah blah bloop  "
```

Instead of mutating the instance they're invoked on, these methods return a *new* instance of `String`.

```
    String text = "  blah blah bloop  ";
    text = text.toUpperCase().trim();
    System.out.println(text);
    // prints "BLAH BLAH BLOOP"
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, JTextArea has a getText and a setText method and String has a toUpperCase method. Check out this example: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/ta_EditTextArea.html

**EDIT**:

This might work:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("some text");
int start = textArea.getSelectionStart();
int end = textArea.getSelectionEnd();
String replace = textArea.getSelectedText().toUpperCase();
textArea.replaceRange(replace, start, end);
```

EIDT 2:

Here is a working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {

JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("some text");

public Test() {

    JButton button = new JButton("upper");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int start = textArea.getSelectionStart();
            int end = textArea.getSelectionEnd();
            String replace = textArea.getSelectedText().toUpperCase();
            textArea.replaceRange(replace, start, end);
        }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(textArea);
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}
}
```

Comment: Its not showing any errors but not working
Can u tel me getSelectionStart() is predefined function?

Answer (score 0):

Swing uses Actions for this type of processing. Functions like cut, copy, paste, select word are all done by Actions. Create your own custom action:

```
class UpperCaseAction extends TextAction
{
    public UpperCaseAction()
    {
        super("UpperCase");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
        int start = cmoponent.getSelectionStart();
        int end = component.getSelectionEnd();
        String replace = component.getSelectedText().toUpperCase();
        component.replaceRange(replace, start, end);
    }
}
```

The benefit of the Action is that it will work on any text component that has focus. You use the Action like:

```
Action action = new UpperCaseAction();
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem( action );
JButton button = new JButton( action );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you just send the text to a variable, change it to uppercase and then send it back.

```
string upper = JTextArea.Text;
upper.toUpperCase();
JTextArea.Text = upper;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faster trick.
In this menu item listener u can write:

```
String selectedText=jTextArea1.getSelectedText();
       if (selectedText==null)return;
       selectedText=selectedText.toUpperCase();
       jTextArea1.replaceSelection(selectedText);
```